# What is the best way to isolate the networks and customers? (kvm/qemu/libvirt)

Tags: ubuntu, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I would like to know how is the best way to "protect" the KVM guests/networks from the others guests in other networks at the same server.

Today I have one dedicated server ruuning KVM/qemu/libvirt and to each customer I have one network subnet. For example:
- Customer_A - 192.168.10.0/29
- Customer_B - 192.168.11.0/29

But the Customer_A can do ping a machine into Customer_B's network and vice-versa.

To try to fix it, I have created a firewall into dedicated server and block there the forward from one network to other but my question is, Can I use for example vlan to avoid one network communicate with other ? What is the best way to isolate the networks and customers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libvirt has a ['nwfilter' object](http://libvirt.org/formatnwfilter.html) which lets you define general firewall rules and associate them with individual NICs given to guests. Libvirt turns these into calls to ebtables/iptables as needed when starting/stopping the guest, or when hotplugging/unplugging the guest. So using that would let you manage firewall rules within the context of libvirt more directly. This is probably the least invasive way to control access between guests, as it doesn't impose requirement to use stuff like vlans to separate guests. Libvirt provides a "clean-traffic" nwfilter definition example that can do MAC & IP address spoofing protection.

One thing to bear in mind is that some customer might want their VM accessible to the entire world, regardless of whether the person connecting is a user from somewhere else on the internet, vs a user on another VM in the same host. eg if customer A is hosting a public facing website, there's little reason why customer B should be blocked from connecting to it.  Using firewall rules probably gives you more flexibility in this respect than fully separating traffic with vlans.